# Running cronjobs in different sessions

Tags: orders, session, cron

We are having a problem whereby two cronjobs are using the `adminhtml/session_quote` to save order information (both jobs are generating orders, one is related to subscriptions and the other importing CSV orders from another site).

At times, we are finding that order items from one job are appearing in the other. We also have a case whereby items from one instance of the job come up in a subsequent instance of the same job.

We have tried clearing `adminhtml/session_quote` but the problem has not been eliminated.

Can instances of cronjobs run on different sessions?

Any input would be appreciated!

Comment: You can try the following: `$session = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote'); $session->setSkiEmptySessionCheck(true); $session->start($sessionName);` and use e.g. get_class($this) of the observer to get a unique session name.

Comment: sessions are not made for getting used from script side. Are you sure, you need them?